# Doxygen: Disable autolink for symbol

Tags: doxygen

I'd like to know if it's possible to exclude a symbol from the autolink functionality.
I have a namespace with a common name (e.g. Ball) and in the documentation I use that name in phrases that are completely unrelated with the namespace (e.g. In soccer you score when the ball enters the goal) and I wouldn't want it linked.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Precede the word with % and doxygen will strip the % and leave the word alone.

```
%Ball
```

Item 11 in the [FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html), but I must admit it took me a while to find it and I knew it was there somewhere!

Comment: +1 - Also, in case anyone else needs this, if you wish to disable ALL of the autolinking, set `AUTOLINK_SUPPORT=NO` in the `doxyfile`. https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/config.html#cfg_autolink_support